# syntax error in json using ajax and php

Tags: json

here is the full code. the error seems to be in the jsonTesting.php page with the variables literature, history and comedy.it's giving me that these variables are not defined.these variables are supposed to be a post from the ajax. please help asap.here is my php page (jsonTesting.php):

```
<?php 
$library=
'{"closets":[
             {"id":"001","theme":"literature","shelves":
                                                           {
                                                            "books":    [{"id":"b1","genre":"english Literature"},
                                                                     {"id":"b2","genre":"arabic literature"},
                                                                     {"id":"b3","genre":"french literature"}  
                                                                        ]
                                                           }
             },
             {"id":"002","theme":"comedy","shelves":{
                                                      "books":[{"id":"b11","genre":"english comedy"},
                                                               {"id":"b22","genre":"arabic comedy"},
                                                               {"id":"b33","genre":"french comedy"}  
                                                              ]
                                                     }
             },
             {"id":"003","theme":"history","shelves":{
                                                       "books":[{"id":"b111","genre":"english history"},
                                                                {"id":"b222","genre":"arabic history"},
                                                                {"id":"b333","genre":"french history"}  
                                                                ]
                                                      }
             }
            ]

}';
//isset is used to make sure that we are reciving the post from the ajax
if(isset($_POST["literature"]))
$literature=$_POST["literature"];

if(isset($_POST["comedy"]))
$comedy=$_POST["comedy"];

if(isset($_POST["history"]))
$history=$_POST["history"];

$library = json_decode($library, true);

 $literatureBooks = $library['closets'][0]['shelves']['books'];
$comedyBooks= $library['closets'][1]['shelves']['books'];
$historyBooks= $library['closets'][2]['shelves']['books'];

if($literature)
{
 echo json_encode($literatureBooks);
 exit();
}

if ($comedy){

 echo json_encode($comedyBooks);
 exit();
}
if($history){
 echo json_encode($historyBooks);
 exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your json response data from jsonTesting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , both are similar only but I achieved using jquery each coz `'each'` will handle both object and json array

```
$.ajax({
      url:"jsonTesting.php",
      data: {literature:'1'},
      type:'POST',
      success:function(data){
       if(data)
       {
        $.each(data,function(key,value){
            $("#books").append('<span>literature Books are'+value.id+'</span><br/>');
        }
      },
      error:function(){
      alert("Error in connection");
         }  
  });
});
```

If this is not working .Make sure your json response from `jsonTesting.php` is correct

Comment: how can i check for my json response from the php page?

Comment: Run that jsonTesting.php directly or add error function in ajax request ...updated the code with error function

Comment: What you getting while running that php file in the browser?

Comment: undefined variables literature, comedy and history

Comment: @lolo512 yes it will show like that coz you POST the value ... just replace this "if(isset($_POST["literature"]))
$literature=$_POST["literature"];" with "$literature ='1';" and check

Comment: ok so here is the problem u are right, but what am i supposed to declare the variables with to get the correct data?

Comment: how i dont know?im a new user here